# How to check whether an EXE has /GS security protection on Windows?

Tags: c++

I receive an EXE from a friend who asked me if the EXE has enabled `/GS` security protection.

Is there any tool that can check this?

I tried PESecurity which can be downloaded from GitHub.

But I got a result without `/GS` option:

```
ALSR True
DEP False
Authentiode False
StrongNaming False
SafeSEH False
ControllFlowGuard False
HVA False
```

Comment: Pretty sure it has to be compiled that way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY::SecurityCookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_load_config_directory32)

> SecurityCookie
>
> A pointer to a cookie that is used by Visual C++ or GS implementation.

Comment: This is incorrect. /GS- binaries still have the security cookie, except the security cookie is not used outside of the initialization function.

Comment: Yes normally it wouldn't matter, but for detecting whether or not a binary was compiled with /GS, your answer doesn't work since the cookie is initialized with /GS- as well.